# Dockingstation resets itself from time to time

Tags: usb, displaylink, docking

I am a linux user for some years now. I have set with Xubuntu on my private laptop (ThinkPad X390) for my daily use and I am really happy with it. I got a nice homeoffice setup by my employer with two monitors and a usb-c dockingstation (dell 6000).

The setup works nice, I got all drivers (esp. DisplayLink) working and the setup is really smooth. My only issue is:

The dockingstation seems to reset itself from time to time.
Monitor turn off and on, wired connection is reseted.

With windows the problem does not happen. I even switched docking stations.

Extract from kern.log

```
Mar  8 20:38:34 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 4586.118587] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar  8 20:58:25 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 5777.348822] perf: interrupt took too long (3141 > 3131), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
Mar  8 21:24:06 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7318.011418] perf: interrupt took too long (3940 > 3926), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50750
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.434195] usb 2-2.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.445487] usb 2-2.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.446639] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enx9cebe8518c8d: unregister 'cdc_ncm' usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, CDC NCM
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.499171] usb 2-2.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.506173] usb 2-2.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.840688] usb 2-2.1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Mar  8 21:24:40 ThinkPad-X390 kernel: [ 7352.872342] usb 2-2.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=767), cval->res is probably wrong.
```

Output of lsusb:

```
21:49:14 knorr@ThinkPad-X390 > [~]: lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 17e9:6006 DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2cb7:0210 FIBOCOM L830-EB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2386:4338 Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0c45:636d Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 06c4:c411 Bizlink International Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1038:184c SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can you guys help me with my problem?
Do you need any more information?

Cheers.
Moritz

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Update the docking station firmware to version A03. The firmware can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=t8y8t) or [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-universal-dock-d6000/drivers).

**Update #1:**

ThinkPad X390

You have BIOS version N2JET92W (1.70 ). There's a newer version 1.72 available [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-X390/downloads/DS539062).

```
  Machine types:  20NX, 20NY, 20Q0, 20Q1
  ---------------------------------------
  Absolute Persistence Module version
  ---------------------------------------

  Package        (ID)     UEFI BIOS (BIOS ID)     ECP (ECP ID)     Rev.  Issue Date
  ----------------------  -------------------  -----------------   ----  ----------
  1.72        (N2JUL31W)    1.72 (N2JET94W)      1.21 (N2JHT37W)   01    2021/03/12
  1.71        (N2JUL30W)    1.71 (N2JET93W)      1.21 (N2JHT37W)   01    2021/01/20
  1.70        (N2JUL29W)    1.70 (N2JET92W)      1.20 (N2JHT36W)   01    2020/09/17
```

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model # and machine type.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Hey heynnema, thank you for your tip! :) I did the firmware upgrade, unfortunatly the problem still persists. :(

Comment: @moritzk Check the USB-C port settings and make sure that it isn't set to "save power" by powering down the port when not in use. Probably have to look at your BIOS settings.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your reply. I checked the BIOS and could not find any setting. I also checked powertop switches: https://imgur.com/a/cZabyUQ

Comment: @moritzk Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: N2JET92W (1.70 )

Comment: Hey Heynnema, will do! I will test the new firmware now for a few hours!

Comment: The problem still persists. :(

Comment: @moritzk I'm out of ideas then. Sorry.

Comment: no worries, thank you very much nevertheless! :)